# Как повторить i в for i in words_1 при условии else?

Tags: python

Есть 2 списка с буквами, один с маленькими - начальный, а второй с большими.
words_1 = ['Q','w','e']
У меня есть цикл for i in word и в нем есть условие if и else.
В if содержится еще один цикл при условии что буква маленькая, а в else изменяется словарь на второй(большие буквы).
Проблема в том что после else цикл for берет букву w.
Можно ли как то вернутся к предыдущей букве Q что бы не дублировать код из if в else?
На самом деле задание там немного больше по этому вот часть кода.

```
keyboard_lower = [['a','b','c','d','e','1','2','3'], ['f','g','h','i','j','4','5','6'], ['k','l','m','n','o','7','8','9'],
                ['p','q','r','s','t','.','@','0'], ['u','v','w','x','y','z','_','/'], ['aA',' ']]
keyboard_upper = [['A','B','C','D','E','1','2','3'], ['F','G','H','I','J','4','5','6'], ['K','L','M','N','O','7','8','9'],
                ['P','Q','R','S','T','.','@','0'], ['U','V','W','X','Y','Z','_','/'], ['aA',' ']]

words_1 = ['Q','w','e']
keybord_changes = keyboard_lower
T_F = False

for j in words_1:
        if j.isupper():
            if T_F:
                for n_s, i in enumerate(keybord_changes):
                    if j in i:
                        print(n_s,keybord_changes[n_s].index(j))
            else:
                s_point = [5,0]
                T_F = True
                keybord_changes = keyboard_upper
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос словесное описание алгоритма. Что за задачу вы решаете?

Comment: А если сменить условие на `if not T_F` и внутренний цикл вынести из условия? Вроде получается тоже самое, что и сейчас.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy codewars TV Remote (symbols).

Comment: @Evrik ну можно и так, просто я подумал изначально может быть есть возможность еще раз повторять цикл с прежней i.

Comment: Ваш код не совпадает с описанием ката. Число раскладок, сами раскладки, способ переключения -  всё другое.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy как кату решить я понял, она не сложная.Единственное что во время выполнения возник вопрос вот это с циклом for, а именно возможность еще раз использовать i.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Извините произошла ошибка, я делаю TV Remote (wrap), а TV Remote (symbols) я оставил в другой вкладке.Там действительно несколько расладок.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обращаться к элементам списка с помощью индексов, т.е. вместо `for j in words_1` использовать `for j in range(len(words_1))` и тогда можете обратиться к предыдущей букве с помощью `words_1[j - 1]`. Если же нужно сделать шаг назад в цикле, то лучше переменную j объявить до цикла и каждую итерацию цикла увеличивать её на 1.

Comment: for не будет так работать, это с while я мог бы так делать при каком то условии.Тут вопрос  именно передачи  через for.Это же не сложное действие, неужели это не возможно сделать?

Comment: В питоне for является типа foreach, т.е. он просто передаёт в переменную последовательно какие-то значения из списка или range, в отличии от C++, например, где for это "специализированный while". К сожалению откатиться на шаг в for'e нельзя(